# DocumentDB not in the CosmosDB API list

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have previously been able to select DocumentDB as the CosmosDB API of choice, when creating a new CosmosDB Account on Azure.

However, recently, this API (DocumentDB) seem to be missing from the list of available choices:

[image: screenshot from azure]

Is DocumentDB deprecated (already), or what? I'm in the South-east Asia region, if that could be the issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `SQL` is `DocumentDB` API.

Comment: Oh, I see. They must have changed the name since I did this the last time. BTW: If you would put your comment as an answer instead, I will mark it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQL` is `DocumentDB` API. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-introduction):

> **The Azure Cosmos DB DocumentDB API or SQL (DocumentDB) API is now
>   known as Azure Cosmos DB SQL API**. You don't need to change anything to
>   continue running your apps built with DocumentDB API. The
>   functionality remains the same.